# How to return an object with $.getJSON when this object is created with his parent class type

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, wcf

Ok, let's say I have these 2 class :

```
namespace CreeContact.CSBDObject.Object
{
    public class BaseObject
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace CreeContact.CSBDObject.Object
{
    public class TestObject : BaseObject
    {
        public string name;
        public TestObject()
        {
            name = "Default";
        }
    }
}
```

I have a wcf service that create an object an return it :

```
namespace CreeContact.WebServices
{

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class Object
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public TestObject createobject()
        {

            TestObject objecttocreate = new TestObject();
            return objecttocreate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I call it with jquery :

```
$.getJSON("WebServices/Object.svc/createobject", function (data) {
    alert(data.d.name);
});
```

When I execute the code like that : **All is working as expected - Alert show "Default".**

But let's say I modify this part :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public TestObject createobject()
{

      TestObject objecttocreate = new TestObject();
      return objecttocreate;
}
```

To this :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public BaseObject createobject()
{

      BaseObject objecttocreate =(BaseObject) new TestObject();
      return objecttocreate;
}
```

**I simply changed the type of the object created to the type his parent.**

**Now I get this error in the javascript : net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.**

I did the verification, the object is created without error in the wcf service. The error come when Jquery get the result.

**Additionnal infos:**

**Here's the object returned for the original request :**

[image]

**Here's the object returned when the type is defined as the parent one :**

[image]

Comment: The error is coming from javascript because no response is being returned. I would investigate your `createobject()` method to determine why nothing is being returned.

Comment: inspect the actual request itself in browser console network tab, can see what is or isn't returned

Comment: Show the actual network response in your browser, not what you see on the backend in visual studio. I suspect your problem is that your object is serialized as `BaseObject` which has no properties, so you get an empty response.

Answer (score 3):

Because if you're downcasting to your base object, there is no `name` member defined, so your web service doesn't send anything to the requester

```
class BaseObject
{
    //This class contains no members
}

class ExtendedObject : BaseObject
{
    public string Name;
}

void Example()
{
    ExtendedObject extended = new ExtendedObject {Name = "Default"};
    BaseObject downcast = (BaseObject)extended;
    //This won't compile - Name is undefined because it's not defined in your base
    downcast.Name;
}
```